# How can I see the name of the Anonda environment?

Tags: anaconda

I have a small problem.
I want to see the name of the environment but I can't see it in the prompt.
I enter the command 'conda env list' every time to see the activate environment.

Does anybody know how to see the name? Please help me...Thanks all!!

[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DOa3.png)

Comment: You've to execute `source activate myenv`. Check this link
https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k/issues/418

Comment: please show us what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the active environment as part of the prompt execute
`conda config --set changeps1 true`. When you set this option from inside a virtual environment do a deactivate / activate first for changes to take effect.